# What's the proper 'direction' to design a query with multiple joins

Tags: sql, oracle

Having information 'A' you want to get information 'E' from your database. These are not directly connected with each other, so you have to select using multiple tables. You achieve this by using `INNER JOIN` for example.

**My question**:

Do you select starting with the target information 'E' writing the query 'reverse'...

```
SELECT 
    E.myTargetColumn
FROM 
    TblE E
INNER JOIN TblD D ON 1=1
INNER JOIN TblC C ON 1=1
INNER JOIN TblB B ON 1=1
INNER JOIN TblA A ON 1=1
WHERE 
    A.ID = myKnownInformation
```

...or do you select starting with the Information 'A', that you already have?

```
SELECT 
    E.myTargetColumn
FROM 
    TblA A
INNER JOIN TblB B ON 1=1
INNER JOIN TblC C ON 1=1
INNER JOIN TblD D ON 1=1
INNER JOIN TblE E ON 1=1
WHERE 
    A.ID = myKnownInformation
```

Both designs somehow make sense to me. Version 1 does, because you directly select the needed column. What I do not like about it is, that you have to think reverse.

`I need this Information, what do i need for that.`

The second version also makes sense to me; You start with the information that you have. What I don't like about it; You have to wait until the last Join is written to actually know what alias the target columns has (`E.myTargetColumn`).

`I have this information, how do i reach my target information?`

**1. Whats the standard for this?

 2. What are pros and contras for and against both designs?**

Additional question; Whats the standard indent for JOINs?

Comment: To paraphrase the answer below, functionally those two queries are different and can return different rows depending on the data. If both queries used `INNER JOIN` they would be functionally the same.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid changed it to INNER JOIN, good point. Still wondering whats commonly preferred or standardized.

Comment: SQL isn't an imperative language, it's a declarative language.  Which means that you express a problem, then the optimiser finds a method to solve it.  For example, using windowed function can introduce additional joins in to the resulting plan, but not necessarily.  By and large the order of the joins in the PLAN is unaffected by the order in the QUERY.  Instead the indexes, statistics and other considerations control what Actually happens.  The best practice for SQL is to write the query in a maintainable way, one that makes it easy to understand and debug, then let the optimiser do its job.

Comment: "I have a filter on table A, I want to get to table E" is a very specific case. Many queries aren't like this. Triangular joins go across three tables. There might be filters on two tables or all three so there is no clear from / to. Personally I usually like to include transactional tables first then lookup tables.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid An example: Table Person contains an AddressID, Table Address contains a CityID, Table Cities contains CountryID, Table Countries contains CountryID and CountryName. You have your PersonID and want to know which country he is from. You will have to select over 4 Tables. But if I understand this correctly it's all about readability without a standard for this specific case. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of your queries is better than the other. Just choose whichever you like better.

It is, however, a common mistake to only think of joins right away. Join, when you want joined information. Let's look at an example:

```
select p.product_name
from product p
join product_order po on po.product_id = p.product_id
where po.order_date > date '2017-04-01';
```

We want to see products that where ordered after April 1, 2017. But what if a product was ordered multiple times since then? Then we'd get the same product multifold. A typical "solution" is to change this to `select distinct p.product_name` then, but it would be way better to select each product only once from the start. Lookups should be done with `EXISTS` or `IN`:

```
select product_name
from product
where product_id in 
  (select product_id from product_order where po.order_date > date '2017-04-01');
```

Now we could argue that your query should best be:

```
select mytargetcolumn
from e
where key1 in
  (select key2 from d where key3 in
    (select key4 from c where key5 in
      (select key6 from b where key7 in
        (select key8 from a where key9 = myKnownInformation)
      )
    )
  )
```

In this small example this is even quite readable. But in more complex situations all those subqueries may be confusing. An alternative would be:

```
select mytargetcolumn
from e
where key1 in
(
  select d.key2
  from d
  join c on d.key3 = c.key4
  join b on c.key5 = b.key6
  join a on b.key7 = a.key8
  where a.key9 = myKnownInformation
);
```

Again none of these two queries is really "better" than the other. (And with the second query we'd again have the "issue" of table order and would wonder if `a.key9 = myKnownInformation` should be in `where` or `on`.)

All this actually boils down to: write your queries as readable as possible. If you consider a certain order in your from clause more readable than another, then use it. But keep in mind: Maybe you don't even want to join after all :-)

Answer (score 3):

The optimiser doesn't care as it will determine the join order itself, but for readability I would always work forwards from what I have rather than backwards from what I want.

```
select e.mytargetcolumn
from   tbla a
       join tblb b
            on  b.somekey = a.somekey
       join tblc c
            on  c.somekey = b.somekey
       join tbld d
            on  d.somekey = c.somekey
       join tble e
            on  e.somekey = d.somekey
where  a.id = myknowninformation
```

(This applies to inner joins. If outer joins are involved then the join order starts making a difference.)

This also goes for the individual predicates, even though the SQL parser doesn't care - it's `b.somekey = a.somekey` and not `a.somekey = b.somekey`, because we are specifying conditions about `b`, the same as `b.job = 'MINION'` and `b.middle_name is null`. See https://jonathanlewis.wordpress.com/2006/11/02/clarity-clarity-clarity and its comments for some discussion about this.

In Oracle at least, the `inner` and `outer` keywords are optional and don't add any information, so I consider them redundant and never use them.

Answer (score 1):

The decision on which table to keep on the left join depends on what you want to achieve. A left join is usually used when the number of unique values of the join criteria in table1 is different from table2.

For example
**Table1:**

```
| id | name|
+----+------+
| 1  | John |
| 2  | Bob  |
| 3  | Brian|
```

**Table2:**

```
| id | subject| marks|
+----+------+------+
| 1  | History| 15   |
| 2  | Maths  | 22   |
| 2  | History| 17   |
```

Here I would do

```
select Table1.name, sum(table2.marks) as total_marks --you will need to handle the null though
from table1
left join table2
  on table1.id = table2.id
group by Table1.name;
```

Basically the table containing all the rows will be first where as the table that does not contain all rows will be on the right.

If the number of values is same then you should use an inner join and the order does not matter. Conventionally people tend to keep the table with the most number of rows in the beginning, else keep the sort of base table in the beginning (i.e. your 2nd example) but that is upto you.

Formatting is subjective, but in my experience I keep code in the same level left aligned with a slight indent in the join criteria. For example

```
select a.column1 ,a.column2 ,a.column3 ,a.column4
                ,a.column5 , table1.column6  -- I indent this and add to the next line if there are lots of select items
      -- I also keep the comma just before the column name so that if I want to comment it out the SQL code does not throw an error due to an extra comma in the previous line
from table1 --Same line because it is just one table
inner join 
(
    --Everything in here will be indented because it is an inner query 
    select * from    --from is in the same line to save space, if there were selected columns it would be in the next line
    table 2
    where id = 1
) a
   on  table1.id = a.id    --I like to indent the on criteria as it helps differentiate between tables, especially in a code like the one that you posted
            and table1.name = a.name    --multiple join criteria is just like multiple select columns
where tabl1.name = "Bob"
```

Comment: About the indent: I really like the idea with the comma right before the column. That makes sense and life easier. Using LEFT JOIN was a bad example for this question - Ill change it to INNER JOIN so the actual question stays in focus. Thank you for your explanation though.